# removing .php ext not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi I am using below code to hide .php extension but it is not working on local as well as live.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php$ $1 [L]
```

please suggest the mistake.
thanks

Comment: You are internally rewriting a request to `example.com/test.php` to `example.com/test` if `test.php` is not a file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to .php extension removal:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: still not working, I am using XAMPP in local, code is not working on livesite either

Comment: Let me assure that this code **definitely works** so it is only due to your local config issue it is not working for you.

Comment: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
 this line is uncommented, should I have to do something else
thanks for your help

Comment: Add `RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [L,R]` rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line and then load `example.com/foo` to see if it is redirected to `/example.com/bar` or not.